# Python: Why do list values change even when not instructed?

Tags: python, list, memory

This is baffling me, two lists are changing in parallel even though the second isn't being touched.

I searched and found I should be using list comprehension to get a new pointer and thus I won't be working with the same list, but NAY it still does the below!
I can't find a reason for this behaviour online.

```
display_order = current_order[:]
print(current_order)
print(display_order)
display_order[0][3] = "CHANGE"
print(current_order)
print(display_order)
```

Output:

```
[['ID', 'Product', '999', 'Section', 'Seat']]
[['ID', 'Product', '999', 'Section', 'Seat']]
[['ID', 'Product', '999', 'CHANGE', 'Seat']]
[['ID', 'Product', '999', 'CHANGE', 'Seat']]
```

Comment: You copy the contents of the outer list, which is (the same) inner list. You would need a deep copy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: List contains objects and you need to copy them. Use: `copy.deepcopy(current_order)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that both variables point to the same inner list in the memory. 
When you do

```
display_order = current_order[:]
```

you get that situation in the memory:

```
display order -----> [['ID', 'Product', '999', 'Section', 'Seat']]
                      ^
                      |
current_order ---------
```

They both point to the same list.

You can avoid that situation with a deep copy of the list which will copy the values of the first list to the new location in memory. Replace the mentioned line with this line:

```
display_order = copy.deepcopy(current_order)
```